# Responsive grid with 1x1, 2x1 and 1x2 items and persistent aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS-Grid and I want try build a tile system where the card all have the same width and height, except when I give them attributes to be double in width or height.
The aspect ratio of the tiles should be 1:1, 1:2 and 2:1. I wanna do this without loosing the responsiveness though. Would be really glad about some help.

It doesn't matter to me that the text would overflow if the first 3 cards would be smaller.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.c-tileset {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    width:621px;
}

.c-tileset ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(185px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(185px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.c-tileset li {
    min-height: 185px;
    min-width: 185px;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
}

.c-tileset li[data-colspan="2"] {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.c-tileset li[data-rowspan="2"] {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.c-tileset p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-tileset">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>A</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>B</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3>C</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
    </li>
    <li data-colspan="2">
      <h3>D</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
    </li>
    <li data-rowspan="2">
      <h3>E</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my case just by continueing trying out various stuff yet I don't rly understand why it work's that way.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.c-tileset {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    width:621px;
}

.c-tileset ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 185px;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.c-tileset li {
    min-height: 185px;
    min-width: 185px;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.c-tileset li[data-colspan="2"] {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.c-tileset li[data-rowspan="2"] {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.c-tileset p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-tileset">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <h3>A</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>B</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <h3>C</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
                            </li>
                            <li data-colspan="2">
                                <h3>D</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
                            </li>
                            <li data-rowspan="2">
                                <h3>E</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint corrupti excepturi impedit beatae, placeat quaerat, eaque aut ipsam provident distinctio quasi rerum earum dolores, facere alias architecto explicabo! Cum, ipsam.</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```